# How do I determine whether a file is an image, regardless of extension, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-io

I am using the m0xie File Api polyfill library and would like to know if a file is actually an image before calling image.load() as it seems that in these cases the onerror event isn't always trigged.

Comment: by its `content-type` :D

Answer (score 0):

the File API (see "[Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)") is your only way if you really don't want to use file extensions. Each File instance has a type property which contains the mime type.

Comment: I tested this but the type property seems to be attained from the file extension.